# StatusStrip label not visible when text too long

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, statusbar, toolstrip

I have a `StatusStrip` docked to the bottom of a C# Form, it contains a label, the text in it displays fine, except when there is longer length of text then it does not display at all, and I have to widen the form and then all of a sudden it appears. Is it possible to show it in the form below:

```
    This is a very long tex...
```

So that the user knows that the app is showing something and then he can widen it himself, because when it is not visible at all, it does not indicate anything to user.

Comment: Just measure the text width and trim it at the status labels width, then SubString() + "...";

Comment: What kind of VS do you use ? I'm using VS2015 Update 3, .NET 4.0, Win10 and it's ok. Text will be truncated if Width of Form less then Width of Text. "...it does not display at all" is not happening on my form.

Comment: @JeremyThompson That's doable but when user extends form I have to refresh it again otherwise it will show incomplete text.

Comment: @x... I am using VS 2010 and .Net framework 3.5

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create a custom renderer based on [`ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and override [`OnRenderItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.onrenderitemtext?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method and draw text with ellipsis:

```
public class CustomRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is ToolStripStatusLabel)
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Text, e.TextFont,
                e.TextRectangle, e.TextColor, Color.Transparent,
                e.TextFormat | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis);
        else
            base.OnRenderItemText(e);
    }
}
```

Then it's enough to set [`Renderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.renderer?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) of your `StatusStrip` to your custom renderer:

```
this.statusStrip1.Renderer = new CustomRenderer();
```

In below example, You can see the behavior of a `ToolStripStatusLabel` which it's [`Spring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripstatuslabel.spring?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property is set to `true` and its `StatusStrip` uses `CustomRenderer`:

[image]

Comment: I'm using VS2015.3 , .NET 4.0, and Win10. That is the default behaviour from label in statusStrip. I dont need to extend it.

Comment: @x... The sample is created using `VS 2013.4` and `.NET 4.5` on `Windows 8.1`. It seems we need a fix.

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei I am on VS 2010 and .Net 3.5 windows 8.1

Comment: Thank for the great solution @RezaAghaei ! Please note that your answer should also include that this will only work if you have set `this.statusStrip1.LayoutStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLayoutStyle.Table;` A LayoutStyle of `HorizontalStackWithOverflow` will NOT work.

Answer (score 10):

If you set

```
ToolStripStatusLabel.Spring = True;
```

then you won't get the "..." but the text will be shown even when the available space is insufficient.

Answer (score 4):

On Visual Studio 2017, the accepted answer didn't work for me. So here is another simple solution.
 Set `LayoutStyle` property of StatusStrip to `Flow`. i.e:

```
 statusStrip1.LayoutStyle= LayoutStyle.Flow;
```

And Set

```
`statusStrip1.AutoSize= false;`
```

Comment: Probably you have made a mistake applying the solution. Make sure you have added a status trip label. Also make sure you have set spring property of the label to true and you are using the renderer which I posted in answer.